# Should avoid global variable used as "parameter" in a function

Tags: c++, global-variables

I'm thinking about a different implementation of this part of a code:

```
unsigned int whyamIexisting=100000; // also good for me static unsigned ...

double rand_number_generation(){


    // create random number [0,1]

    static unsigned int rand_counter=0;

    rand_counter++;

    if( rand_counter > whyamIexisting) {
        update_my_seed(time(NULL));
        rand_counter=0;
    }
    // random number generation 
    return thats_your_gorgeous_numb(); // random algorithm
}

main(){

    ...modify whyamIexising

    ...use rand_number_generation() several times

    ...

 }
```

Should I not use global variable? And if yes what solution will you suggest?

thanks!

Comment: I don't get it... whats the point of having a global variable if you use it only in the scope of your main() function ? It should be declared as non global, inside the scope of your main() function...

Comment: Your example doesn't use the global variable, so we can't offer any suggestions apart from removing it completely. Is it meant to be the random number generator's state? In that case it might be better as a member of a RNG class.

Comment: Sorry! There was an error in the code: now whyamIexisting is used! In function  rand_number_generation()

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with multiple functions and using a global variable, i would suggest you not to modify it and instead use local variable for storing it and then do the modification.

I usually avoid using global variables.   :-)

Answer (score 0):

There... gone!

```
double rand_number_generation(unsigned int whyamIexisting){

    // create random number [0,1]

    static unsigned int rand_counter=0;

    rand_counter++;

    if( rand_counter > whyamIexisting) {
        update_my_seed(time(NULL));
        rand_counter=0;
    }
    // random number generation 
    return thats_your_gorgeous_numb(); // random algorithm
}

main(){

    unsigned int limit = 17;

    ...use rand_number_generation(limit) several times

    ...

 }
```

There is no point having a global variable in your case. It only makes the program hard to maintain if it were to grow. It doesn't add anything in the example you have given.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the rest of code, so it's based on fragments you posted and may be completely wrong.

`whyamIexisting` is kind of a description for environment where `rand_number_generation` is run, but it also describes it's state, same as `rand_counter`.

From tags I see that you write in C++, which is an object oriented language. The thing about object orientation is that you have, you know, objects. Probably not everyone will agree with me (thinking about my High School IT teacher), but I personally consider putting everything that has it's own state into class as a good practise. Does object containing `whyamIexisting` as it's field, `rand_counter` as another and `rand_number_generation` as it's method (and probably getter and setter for `whyamIexisting`) solve your problem?

Unless you don't use `whyamIexisting` anywhere else in the code, because then you can simply make it local in main and pass as parameter to function `rand_number_generation`.